# Custom function for animate.css causing problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animate.css

I'm using the `animate.css` library for my project. I thought it would be easier to create a jQuery function that would do most of the work for me. Here is the function:

```
$(function () {    
    $.fn.extend({
        animateCss: function (animationName, callback) {
            var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
            this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
                if(callback){
                    callback();
                };
            });
        }
    });

});
```

It works, I can call it from jQuery objects. The problem is that when I pass in a callback function from one object, it gets called, but the same function from that object gets called again when ANOTHER object calls the function without passing in a callback.

I'm not quite sure how this can happen, I come from a Java background. Is there some way that this function can retain the callback variable passed in for other objects?

Comment: Why aren't you simply adding the animate css classes to your html?

Comment: @NathanielFlick I need to remove the classes after adding them, that way they can be used again. Also, I wan't a function to run after the animation is done. That is why I have encapsulated the functionality in this function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, I've used the bare minimum here, but the beauty of css3 is that it doesn't require javascript to run, just the browser to interpret it; hence css3 only works so far back.

[All the animation documentation is here](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), and here's one simple example of bounce:

```css
.title-large {
  font-size: 48px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bounce animated title-large">Animate me</div>
```

My guess is either you don't have access to the html or want to let different animations be added dynamically? Either way you can add any classes you want and remove them after the animation is complete, which is what I think they are doing on the github demo page link above. Hope this helps!

Comment: I do want animations to be added dynamically. Also, this function allows for me to reuse code. Instead of constantly removing classes after the animation is complete on every single animation, this function simplifies the code. I just need to find out why the callback is having problems.

Comment: <script>
  function testAnim(x) {
    $('#animationSandbox').removeClass().addClass(x + ' animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
      $(this).removeClass();
    });
  };

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.js--triggerAnimation').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var anim = $('.js--animations').val();
      testAnim(anim);
    });

    $('.js--animations').change(function(){
      var anim = $(this).val();
      testAnim(anim);
    });
  });

</script>

Comment: That script I posted in the comment is exactly what Animate css is using for their callback which is really a global function that they can then call, filling in variable "x" with the animation they want to use/run.

Comment: It would be good to see the rest of your code, namely the html and css so we can diagnose.

Comment: You do have a this being called that looks incorrect (missing parentheses): this.addClass, so it's not a proper selector.

Comment: I added the parentheses, still problematic. If you look here "https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/README.md" And search for function. The function I use is the one you see there. The only difference is that I added a callback. This may help.

Comment: Putting callback = null; after calling the callback fixes the problem. I don't know how, but callback is still equal to the callback that I pass in through another variable function call. I'm not sure why this variable would crossover into other variables. Strange...

Comment: You must be clearing the callback so it can be used again. Sounds logical, but sorry I didn't think of that first. :)